# 2018-02-21T10:49:21.951-0800 E QUERY [thread1] TypeError: db.createColletion is not a function :

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to create a collection in mongoDB, it throws an error

> 2018-02-21T10:49:21.951-0800 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: db.createColletion is not a function :

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled createCollection.
"createColletion" isn't a function, because it's not spelled correctly.